# Setting up Sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am new to mongodb, after install hortonworks HDP cluster and embedded mongodb with 3 nodes at HDP cluster.

now, try to setup shardings with mongodb. I tried few things and executed few steps. when I mongo, I saw these 3 servers have shard0:PRIMARY, shard1:SECONDARY> and shard1:SECONDARY>
Q1. did this mean I have sharding working?
Q2. if this is not right, how to remove all settings and back to a initial settings?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting. Standard blurb said,.Your question lacks in detail even for the correct site. When re-posting please include the steps followed to re-produce your problem.

Comment: Or basically start again from a tutorial: [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. Yes, you have managed to start Replica Set, not cluster.

[Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) is group of mongod nodes or replica sets where sharded collections exists. Sharding is like oracle partitioning.

If you are building cluster, it's better to do it with replica sets, so every shard in cluster is one replica set of (at least) three nodes.

Comment: thank you so much JJussi for answer my question. can you please give me some hints to start cluster or whatever need to do from here?

Comment: Updated my answer about cluster